# Setting JAVA environment variable

Tags: java, environment-variables, openjdk, jdk

I am setting up new Ubunut machine. Stuck on setting up Java environment variable. I have tried all possible way and whatever solution I found here. None of them worked. It is still giving me blank line (see the code first line). Can anyone help me to set the variable.

```
me@me-ubuntu:~|⇒  echo "$JAVA_HOME"

me@me-ubuntu:~|⇒  java -version
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b25)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
me@me-ubuntu:~|⇒  
me@me-ubuntu:~|⇒  which java
/usr/bin/java
me@me-ubuntu:~|⇒  ls -l /usr/lib/jvm
total 8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   24 Mar 22  2014 default-java -> java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Jan 27 09:22 java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 -> java-7-openjdk-amd64
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Mar 31 10:26 java-7-openjdk-amd64
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Mar 31 10:43 java-8-oracle
me@me-ubuntu:~|⇒
```

I tried to set it in `~/.bashrc` as well as in `environment` file but nothing work

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Comment: Please list what you have already tried.

Comment: @A.B.please see my edited question

Comment: What do you get if you do ".   $HOME/.bashrc"   and then "echo $JAVA_HOME"  ?

Comment: @Scooter I am sorry, but can you please tell me where to add it? in terminal or in file?

Comment: Two commands to type at the command prompt in the terminal window.

Comment: nothing happen.